# Gridview Load next set of rows on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which is displaying 100 rows from the database.

I want it to show just the first 10 rows in the beginning.
When person scrolls to the bottom, he clicks on a "load more" button. It will load the next 10 rows below the previous 10 rows. And so on.
How to implement this?
I tried finding solution but struggling with it.

Comment: search about gridview paging.

Comment: Its called infinite scroll. Hope this article will help you: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Endless-Scroll-Infinite-Scroll-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: i hope it helpful for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx

Comment: Paging displays in a new page. And it displays only the next 10 rows. Not the new 10 rows below the previous 10 rows.